# Marketing Cloud SOAP API UpdateRequest response Bad Request

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, error

I'm trying to send a SOAP request to the Marketing Cloud API so I can unsuscribe a person from a list but the response always is "Bad Request".

Here is the request I'm sending:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>--USERNAME--</Username>
        <Password>--PASSWORD--</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
        <EmailAddress>--PERSON EMAIL TO UNSUSCRIBE--</EmailAddress>
        <Lists>
          <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
          <ID>59</ID>
          <Status>Unsubscribed</Status>
          <Action>Update</Action>
        </Lists>
      </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Method: POST
The endpoint is: https://XXXXXXX.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx

And the parameters in the header are:
Content-Type:text/xml
SOAPAction:Update
Accept:text/xml
Charset:UTF-8

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Have you enabled username and password API authentication in Security Settings?

Comment: Have you validated your call in like soap UI?

Comment: Also have you tried leveraging this example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_an_existing_subscriber_using_the_create_method_with_updateadd.htm

Comment: If you have than one BU it can also be a missing clientId.. so now you have lots of stuff to check.. get back to us with any news :)

Answer (score 0):

In the header, could you try this ->

```
Content-Type : text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPAction : Update
```